Why are there newlines at the end of my environment variables?
.env:
FOO=bar
BAZ=qux

Bash to test:
(sdg-watchdog) export $(cat .env | xargs) && bash -c 'echo ${FOO: -1}'

(sdg-watchdog) export $(cat .env | xargs) && bash -c 'echo ${FOO: -2}'
r


The issue was that my env file had CRLF line endings. Switching to LF solved the problem.
